# Load WinForm Object from CliXml PS

Tags: winforms, powershell

How can one save and load the properties of GUI objects from a CliXml file?   Saving mwe is below, with failed attempt to load commented out. directly importing changes object type from `System.Windows.Forms.Button` to `System.Management.Automation.PSObject`. Attempts to loop over the saved properties failed.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,100)
$form.text = "Form"
$form.TopMost = $false
$form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedSingle"
$form.MaximizeBox = $false

$TestButton = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$TestButton.text = "Test"
$TestButton.width = 85
$TestButton.height = 30
$TestButton.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0)
$TestButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',12)
$TestButton.Enabled = $true

$path = "./vars/test.xml"
$TestButton | Export-CliXml $path

$TestButton.Enabled = $false

#$TestButton.GetType().FullName #For comp below
#$TestButton = Import-CliXml $path #Import the saved properties - intention is that this enables button again
#$TestButton.GetType() #The import changes the type. How to load saved properties and avoid this? 

$form.Controls.Add($TestButton)
[void]$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: A `System.Windows.Forms.Button` is not marked as serializable, so exporting it with Export-CliXml and re-importing it is not possible.You will have to write your own custom functions for that..

Comment: Ah - I had assumed the inverse, since a file in indeed generated, or, indeed, a string of I serialise. Is there a test for serialisability outside of documentation? Or is my code above it? EDIT: Type.IsSerialisable. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not "serialize" and save it as a PowerShell expression:

```
{
    New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
        text = "Test"
        width = 85
        height = 30
        location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0)
        Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',12)
        Enabled = $true
    }
} | Out-File .\Vars\Test.ps1
```

<sub>*Note:* using the outer curly brackets will validate the expression, but you might also just use (here) quotes</sub>

And then load it using [dot-sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing):

```
$TestButton = . .\Vars\Test.ps1
```

Comment: What the MWE does not show is I was looking for a way to take all of the attributes of a non-serializable object and save them (I tried with the disable before the save). The hope was that I could loop through a whole Form and have a quick way to save / load everything. I have a well populated user drive-GUI for a test set with many boxes / buttons. Was hoping to add a load/save feature without writing a text-grabber for text boxes, a check/uncheck for tickboxes etc...